# Angular2 Can't resolve all parameters for RouterOutlet: (RouterOutletMap, ViewContainerRef, ?, name)

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I'm totally new to any JS framework. Just started learning Angular 2. I'm doing some basic app for internship. From angular app I post name to Java controller, that get's info needed and sends it back. Basically fun happens when name is 'Dave' or 'Hal'.
All looks fine, but when I run server and try to get to my app, I get

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Can't resolve all parameters for RouterOutlet: (RouterOutletMap, ViewContainerRef, ?, name).

As far as I can tell from documentation, the missing parameter is `componentFactoryResolver`. How to get rid of this error and run it all properly.

Here are the files:

the `app/main.ts`

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
])
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

the `app/app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Names';
}
```

the `app/app.routes.ts`

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';

import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { DaveComponent } from './dave.component';
import { HalComponent } from './hal.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/hello' },
    { path: 'index.html', redirectTo: '/hello' },
    { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent },
    { path: 'dave', component: DaveComponent },
    { path: 'hal', component: HalComponent }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

the `app/hello.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hello',
    templateUrl: 'app/hello.component.html'
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit{
    public name = 'stranger';

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: Http) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.name = 'stranger';
    }

    sendName(name: string) {
        this.post(name);
    }

    post(name: string) {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

        this.http
            .post('names', name, {headers: headers})
            .subscribe((res:Response) => this.processResponse(res),
                (err) => this.handleError(err));
    }

    processResponse(response: Response) {
        if (response.status == 418) {
            return;
        } else if (response.json().page == "/dave" || response.json().page == "/hal") {
            let messageString = response.json().message;
            this.router
                .navigate([response.json().page, { queryParams: { message: messageString } }]);
        } else {
            this.name = response.json().name;
        }
    }
    handleError(error: any) {
        this.name = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    }
}
```

the `app/hal.component.ts` (`dave.component.ts` looks almost the same but with *dave* in places of *hal*)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from './user';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hal',
    templateUrl: 'app/hal.component.html'
})
export class HalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    user =  new User();
    sub: any;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.user.message = params['message'];
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do a plunker so we can try it? Also, do you need `terminal: true` in your route as shown here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect

Comment: @DeborahK I could, but don't know how to make it work on the fly. I mean all node dependencies, Java core and stuff.

Comment: Can't resolve all parameters for RouterOutlet: (RouterOutletMap, ViewContainerRef, ?, name).

Comment: @DeborahK 
Following is a small working example of routing as shown on the official website

https://github.com/lohiarahul/Angular2-Silverlight-Starter

It breaks as soon as I upgrade the router version to the recent beta release.
And btw, great series on pluralsight, I got started there.

Comment: @lohiarahul I followed official docs and tutorials from angular.io but it breaks. After some fiddling with files, now it works but now I have problems with query parameters. What I did listed below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't have to reverse router version. All that works now on 3.0.0-beta.1.

Now it works as supposed, I'm not getting that error anymore (not like I dont get others now, but that have nothing to do with question).

**WHAT I DID** *sorted by plausibility of resolving issue*

1. Precompiled components in **app.component**

   `precompile: [HelloComponent, HalComponent, DaveComponent]`
2. Redirecting now set to full path match

   `export const routes: RouterConfig = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/hello', pathMatch: 'full' }
        ...
    ];`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone having this issue.

This could happen when one Angular dependency gets updated through npm while some other internal component points to a previous version.

The question mark in the error means that Angular failed to provide an instance to the third DI parameter in the RouterOutlet component. When examined closely in the Debugger we can clearly see (And by clearly I mean after reading the line 2486 of the routing.umd.js file) that the third parameter "ComponentFactoryResolver" is missing.

> Can't resolve all parameters for RouterOutlet: (RouterOutletMap,
>   ViewContainerRef, ?, name)

I recommend the following steps.

1. npm uninstall @angular --save
2. Update your packages.json with the latest dependencies from https://angular.io/guide/quickstart
3. npm install

Comment: Have you any idea why precompiling resolved the issue? I have not updated any dependencies and it works like a charm now.

Comment: Well, in a perfect scenario where every library is loaded perfectly you still need the precompile attribute. You would, however, get a different error. It's very difficult to tell why you got the error you got with all libraries perfectly loaded but I guess I have to say that Angular JS2 RC4 is still not a fully RTM version so things like this could be expected - I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I too got this error "Can't resolve all parameters for RouterOutlet: (RouterOutletMap, ViewContainerRef, ?, name)."

For me, the routing breaks after I upgrade to 3.0.0-beta.1 from 3.0.0-alpha.8. Trying reverting back to the alpha version.

Comment: "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4"


I hadn't updated these these from rc.3 to rc.4. Upgrading these, solved my problem.