# How can I upgrade the version of router in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am currently using this : @angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.7 & I want to upgrade it to @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2.
This is my app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import {SubjectsComponent} from './subjects.component';
import {ProfileDetailsComponent} from './profileDetails.component';
import {AgreementComponent} from './agreement.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
 { path: 'subjects', component: SubjectsComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileDetailsComponent },
 { path: 'agreement', component: AgreementComponent }
 ];

  export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
 ];
```

I've changed the version of router, changed the the rc.3 to rc.4, still getting the same error. Here's my package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~0.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/list": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/progress-bar": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/radio": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/tabs": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

Comment: Thought you just have to change the version number in your package.json then npm install it. Well that's how I'm doing it at least.

Comment: I did the same & got this : EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for RouterOutlet: (RouterOutletMap, ViewContainerRef, ?, name). So I thought maybe I was doing something wrong..

Comment: Can you share your RouterConfig code? I guess you are missing  pathMatch: 'full'

Comment: @Sanket I've added the code, can you tell me where am I suppose to add pathMatch: 'full' ?

Comment: pathMatch: 'full' is NOT required since you are not redirecting using redirectTo.

Comment: Try adding precompile as mentioned in the answer of this post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154612/angular2-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-routeroutlet-routeroutletmap-viewco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just go to your package.json and change

--------> "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha-7" to  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",

and then go to terminal and type npm install .

and this will do what you want :)

this is your answer :---

### just update your package.json file with the following code

### "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4", "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4", "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4", "@angular/forms": "0.2.0", "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4", "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4", "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1", "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2", "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4"

i have tested this and this works fine now :)

Comment: Thanks :) I did exactly the same & got this :  EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for RouterOutlet: (RouterOutletMap, ViewContainerRef, ?, name).

Comment: before this i was also getting the same error but now its resolved :)

Comment: Am I supposed to add these both: "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1", "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2"    ?

Comment: yes ,router deprecated is also needed in routing in angular 2

Comment: Thanks a tonne!! Got rid of that error & it is working, not completely but much better than the way it was before :) I am getting this now if you could help : Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Error: Cannot match any routes: ''  at Observable.eval [as _subscribe]

Comment: not sure about it but u should add a new route for ' ' .. u can do this as   {
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/yourpath',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}

Comment: Thanks its working now, some other error was present I guess... :)

Comment: That's great .. Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont use `@angular/router-deprecated` anymore in your package.json 
Update your package.json like this way :)

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
     "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "leaflet": "^0.7.7",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^1.2.3",
    "ng2-toastr": "^0.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
```

Then do a `npm install` in your command prompt/terminal

Comment: I had the same set of dependencies & it wasnt working, guess router-deprecated is actually required ....